# What's the point of g++ -Wreorder?

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-warnings

The g++ -Wall option includes -Wreorder.  What this option does is described below.  It is not obvious to me why somebody would care (especially enough to turn this on by default in -Wall).

```
-Wreorder (C++ only)
  Warn when the order of member initializers given in the code does not
  match the order in which they must be executed.  For instance:

    struct A {
      int i;
      int j;
      A(): j (0), i (1) { }
    };

  The compiler will rearrange the member initializers for i and j to
  match the declaration order of the members, emit-ting a warning to that
  effect.  This warning is enabled by -Wall.
```

Comment: Some good answers here, but a brief aside in case it's of interest to anyone: g++ has a flag to treat this as a full-blown error: `-Werror=reorder`

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Consider:

```
struct A {
    int i;
    int j;
    A() : j(0), i(j) { }
};
```

Now `i` is initialized to some unknown value, not zero.

Alternatively, the initialization of `i` may have some side effects for which the order is important. E.g.

```
A(int n) : j(n++), i(n++) { }
```

Comment: This should really be the example in the documentation.

Comment: thanks.  With most of our types being POD types with simple initializers this didn't occur to me.  Your example is much better than the g++ manual example.

Comment: The example in this is answer is terribly confounding. When I tested this I found that `i` was **consistently initialized** to `0`, which makes it seem like nothing is erroneous. But if you use something like `100` then you see that `j` is `100` and `i` is `0`. I know it's probably due to the compiler but I'm using whatever default g++ I get with Ubuntu so it should be a common occurrence.

Comment: @Mike this is because your compiler (gcc) initializes uninitialized variables to 0, but this isn't something that you should depend on; i being 0 is just a side-effect of the unknown value for uninitialized variables is 0.

Comment: The code origins from the manpage of gcc (http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc) but is not cited!

Comment: @codingdave Are you sure the order goes man page -> this, and not the other way around?

Comment: @Yakk The order was man page-> SO answer. Here is an archive of the man page from 2007 that lists this example explicitly. The upvoted comment from Ben S is a hilarious example of someone suggesting that something exist without even checking that it does already. http://web.archive.org/web/20070712184121/http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc

Comment: The question asks about the code from the manpage of gcc and points out that it doesn't really demonstrate why -Wreorder is useful. I came up with a better example that better illustrates the problem. This code is still *not* in the gcc docs.

Comment: @KymikoLoco That is just plain wrong. The example in the man page is the one from the OP (where `i` is initialized to `1`). Here, `i` is initialized to `j`, which actually demonstrates a problem.

Comment: @jazzpi Heh, you're right. I checked and rechecked and didn't catch that one character change, as I'm sure codingdave missed as well. In any case, codingdave is incorrect, it's not cited because it's not in the man pages. Ben S is actually correct, it should be an example (or *the* example). And I'm wrong because this SO answer is not in the man pages, in the past OR present.

Comment: Why does `i` get initialised to an unknown value in the snippet?

Comment: @Nubcake because the order of initialization is the order of the variables in the class, not the order of the initializers in the constructor.  At the time `i` is initialized, `j` hasn't been initialized yet.

Answer (score 57):

The problem is that somebody might see the list of member initialisers in the constructor, and think that they're executed in that order (j first, then i). They are not, they are executed in the order the members are defined in the class.

Suppose you wrote `A(): j(0), i(j) {}`. Somebody might read that, and think that i ends up with the value 0. It doesn't, because you initialised it with j, which contains junk because it has not itself been initialised.

The warning reminds you to write `A(): i(j), j(0) {}`, which hopefully looks a lot more fishy.

Comment: Looks/smells fishy indeed! :)  Definitely code smell :)  Thanks for your clear explanation that is right to the point. :)

Comment: "... reminds you to write A(): i(j), j(0) {} ..."
I suggest that it reminds you to reorder the class members in this particular case.

Answer (score 30):

Other answers have provided some good examples that justify the option for a warning. I thought I'd provide some historical context. The creator of C++, Bjarne Stroustrup, explains in his book [The C++ programming language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201889544) (3rd edition, Page 259):

> The members’ constructors are called before the body of the containing class’ own constructor is executed. The constructors are called in the order in which they are declared in the class rather than the order in which they appear in the initializer list. To avoid confusion, it is best to specify the initializers in declaration order. The member destructors are called in the reverse order of construction.

Comment: This is the first answer that shows how to properly fix the issue

Answer (score 13):

This can bite you if your initializers have side effects. Consider:

```
int foo() {
    puts("foo");
    return 1;
}

int bar() {
    puts("bar");
    return 2;
}

struct baz {
    int x, y;
    baz() : y(foo()), x(bar()) {}
};
```

The above will print "bar" then "foo", even though intuitively one would assume that order is as written in the initializer list.

Alternatively, if `x` and `y` are of some user-defined type with a constructor, that constructor may also have side effects, with the same non-obvious result.

It can also manifest itself when initializer for one member references another member.

Answer (score 8):

The warning exists because if you just read the constructor, it looks like `j` is getting initialized before `i`. This becomes a problem if one is used to initialize the other, as in

```
struct A {
  int i;
  int j;
  A(): j (0), i (this->j) { }
};
```

When you just look at the constructor, this *looks* safe. But in reality, `j` has not yet been initialized at the point where it is used to initialize `i`, and so the code won't work as expected. Hence the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of good answers already, but there's one thing missing - *why* is the initialization order the way it is?

The order of initialization of class members is **not** the order that initializers are listed in the constructor, it's the order they're declared in the class itself.  The reason why is a bit subtle.

C++ guarantees that the order of destruction will be the opposite of the order of construction for member variables.  Since a class can have multiple constructors with different initializer lists, the destructor would need to know that order which would be a big bookkeeping problem and introduce unnecessary overhead.  The solution is to force every constructor to use the same order of initialization for members so that the destruction order can be fixed as well.

Since you can't use the initializer order, the only choice is to use the declaration order.

While it is perfectly legal for C++ to initialize the variables in a different order than the initializer list, it's a non-intuitive source of possible bugs.  The warning lets you know to look for those bugs, or to reorder your initializer list to reflect reality.

Comment: I was asked about initializer order once in an interview, and I got it wrong.  I asked for an explanation from the interviewer, and learned something that day.  Time to pass it along.