# Why isn't g++ -Wreorder smarter?

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

Looking at [What's the point of g++ -Wreorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828037/whats-the-point-of-g-wreorder), I fully understand what `-Wreorder` is useful for.  But it doesn't seem unreasonable that the compiler would be able to detect whether such a reordering is harmless:

```
struct Harmless {
  C() : b(1), a(2) {}
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

or broken:

```
struct Broken {
  C() : b(1), a(b + 1) {}
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

My question is then: why doesn't GCC detect (and warn about) the actual use of an undefined member in an initializer instead of this blanket warning on the ordering of initializers?

As far as I understand, `-Wuninitialized` only applies to automatic variables, and indeed it does not detect the error above.

---

EDIT:

A stab at formalizing the behavior I want:
Given initializer list `: a1(expr1), a2(expr2), a3(expr3) ... an(exprn)`, I want a warning if (and only if) the execution of any of the initializers, in the order they will be executed, would reference an uninitialized value. I.e. in the same manner as `-Wuninitialized` warns about use of uninitialized automatic variables.

Some additional background: I work in a mostly windows-based company, where basically everybody but me uses Visual Studio.  VS does not have this warning, thus nobody cares about having the correct order (and have no means of knowing when they screw up the ordering except manual inspection), thus leaving me with endless warnings that I have to constantly fix everytime someone breaks something.  I would like to be informed about only the cases that are really problematic and ignore the benign cases.  So my question is maybe better phrased as: is it technically feasible to implement a warning/error like this?  My gut feeling says it is, but the fact that it isn't already implemented makes me doubt it.

Comment: Submit a bug report if you think it's a bug. Anyway, here's what I [get](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/69eeca3016360f9b).

Comment: At least come up with a formal way to state whether an initializer list `: a1(expr1), a2(expr2), a3(expr3) ... an(exprn)` deserves a warning.

Comment: It can be confusing when you debug a program where the members in initialization list are in different order than they are defined in the class. Even if the members are independent.

Comment: @remyabel I don't think it's a bug, I think it is a missing (highly useful) feature. But you are right that I should probably take it to the GCC team if I want it implemented. I was trying to find out if there is any particular reason this feature would be hard to implement.

Answer (score 4):

My speculation is that it's for the same reason we have `-Wold-style-cast`: safety erring on the side of being too conservative.  All it takes is a moment's inattention to transform `Harmless` into `CarelessMistake`.  Maybe this developer's in a hurry or has an older version of GCC or sees that it's "just a warning" and presses on.

This is basically true among many warnings.  They often are spurious, and require a little bit of restructuring to compile cleanly, but on some occasions they represent real problems.  Every good programmer will prefer some working through some false positives if that means they get fewer *false negatives*.

I would be surprised if there's a valid direct answer to the question.  There's no technical reason I see that it couldn't be done.  It's just . . . why bother trying to figure out if something questionable is actually okay?  Programming is the human's job.

---

As a personal reason, I think initializing variables in the order you declare them often makes sense.

Comment: As long as the compiler detects and outputs an error for the CarelessMistake, I don't see a reason to keep the order the same in the header and implementation. It's just unnecessary work for all but those (rare) careless mistakes.

Comment: And while programming is the human's job, humans are lazy and many will ignore the stream of benign warnings and miss the important ones. But I guess what you're saying is that it could be done, it's just that nobody has cared enough to do it yet?