# C++:Correctly initializing constructor of abstract class

Tags: c++, abstract-class

What is the correct way to initialize a constructor of an abstract class? I commented out the constructor in the cc file and it seemed to be working, I would like to understand why.

Board. h
Board.h is an abstract class, as it has 2 pure virtual function NOT included here.

```
class Board {
public:
   Board(size_t width, size_t height)
    : width(width), height(height) {}

   virtual ~Board() {}
....

protected:
//this is line 54
size_t height;
size_t width;
};
```

My localBoard.h

```
#include <Board.h>
class LocalBoard : public Board {

public:

  LocalBoard(size_t width, size_t height) :Board(width),Board(height) {}

  ~LocalBoard() {}

 ...
};
```

LocalBoard.cc

```
#include <board/LocalBoard.h>
    // commenting this out fixed the error
    //LocalBoard(size_t width, size_t height) {}

error: multiple initializations of constructor
```

On an another note may someone help me understand what the following warning means, what consequences it has for my program and how to fix it? I think it related to the constructor again.

```
  ./include/board/Board.h: In constructor ‘Board::Board(size_t, size_t)’:
  ./include/board/Board.h:54:9: warning: ‘Board::width’ will be              initialized    after [-Wreorder]
   size_t width;
```

Comment: Board(width, height) - but your book would've told you this ;)

Comment: `Board(width),Board(height)` -> `Board(width, height)`

Comment: class Board as provided here is not an abstract class, It would be better to add a pure virtual function here to make it abstract.

Comment: @WernerHenze you can't see the whole class - how do you know it doesn't have a pure virtual function already  -  infact the question explictly states it has 2?

Comment: "On another note": Please don't do that!  One question per question please.  If you want to ask that as a separate question, that is fine (but do check it hasn't already been asked first.)

Comment: You have `Board(width)` but you don't have a ctor for `Board` that takes only 1 argument??

Comment: @WernerHenze Why are you mentioning me?  I only said the OP should not ask a second question (on initialization order warning).

Comment: @MartinBonner Sorry, my fault.

Comment: @UKMonkey I did not say that Board is not Abstract. I just said that if the OP thinks that it is important that Board is Abstract, then it is a good idea to also Show that in the code and not only mention it in the question. It's just one additional line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already provided an inline implementation of class LocalBoard's ctor in this line:

```
LocalBoard(size_t width, size_t height) :Board(width),Board(height) {}
```

You cannot give the same ctor twice (once inline and once in the cc file).

You need to write either

```
class LocalBoard {
    LocalBoard(size_t width, size_t height) :Board(width, height) {}
};
```

or

```
class LocalBoard {
    LocalBoard(size_t width, size_t height);
}

// probably in the cc file:
LocalBoard::LocalBoard(size_t width, size_t height) : Board(width, height)
{
}
```

Please note that I changed your two base class ctor calls `Board(width),Board(height)` to one base class ctor call `Board(width, height)`.

Regards the warning you can look at [What's the point of g++ -Wreorder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828037/whats-the-point-of-g-wreorder).

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that the OP's inline implementation is wrong - you can't call the base class constructor twice - you have to call it once with two parameters.

Comment: @MartinBonner Good Point, done!